# jQuery datatables - Filter by select input when input has html/images inside <td></td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I am trying to filter my table with select inputs [DataTables with select inputs DEMO](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

The problem I have is my `<table>` has several images/sprites etc. inside the `<td>` and I would like datatables to use the `<span class="hidden-val">` values inside them.

Example:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <span style="display:none" class="hidden-val">23</span>
    <i class="my-sprite-abc>My Logo</i>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I managed datatables to show the correct select input values by converting the string into DOM HTML and then get the `innerText`, but I still struggle with the `column.search.draw()` part, since I don't know how to teach datatables to use the hidden span values.

```
$('#my-table').DataTable( {

        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    console.log($(this).val());
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                        );

                    column
                    .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                    .draw();
                } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    var html_val = $.parseHTML(d)
                    //console.log(html_val);

                    if (html_val != null){ // check if html is not null
                        var new_d = $(html_val)[0].innerText // take first html object <span> in this case
                        select.append( '<option value="'+new_d+'">'+new_d+'</option>' )
                    }

                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
```

Thanks, if you can help me with this!

[image: Select Input]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [**type based search plugin**](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/#Type-based-search) that let you filter on `hidden-val` only :

```js
jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.type.search.hiddenVal = function(data) {
    return $('<div>').append(data).find('.hidden-val').text()
}
```

and set this as `type` for the column that has the `hidden-val` :

```js
...
columnDefs: [
    { type: "hiddenVal", targets: [0] } //fist column as example
],
...
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/dtuv0qhj/**

Comment: Thank you for this, but I need this for the select inputs dropdown :). Look at the footer of my demo :)

Comment: @zer02, the above type filter is general / global for the dataTable - it will work with your `column.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ).draw();` too

Comment: I tried that code. It works for the search input. But it breaks with select inputs. It will still display html code `23 > 23` as select

Comment: @zer02 - I'll get back to you when I come home, have 1½ hours traveltime. It is very easy to overcome, so in the meantime you probably have found the solution yourself :)

Comment: Hey, I cannot find the solution :/

Comment: @zer02, it works with selects too -> http://jsfiddle.net/dtuv0qhj/1/ is your concern the option values of the <select>? You could use a column.render method instead of a type based filter, but dont know how your table is created - i.e is it a DOM <table> or do you get the rows via AJAX .

Comment: Hey, I found my error. The reason why it didn't work was that I indented the `<span style="display:none" class="hidden-val">   23  </span>` with a new line and also he looked for spaces between `span`. Thank you

Comment: That worked for the first column I will try to upload my table in jsfiddle. The others still making problems.

Comment: @zer02 - use `targets: [0,1,2]` if it should target the first 3 columns, `targets: [0 2 4]` if it should target the first, the third and the fifth column and so on.

Comment: Yes!, I did it now, before you wrote forgot everything works now thanks alot david!